# Add Post Url to Manage Edit Screen

Tags: custom-post-types, columns, post-meta

I'm trying to add a column to the manage screen that displays the Title and url of the post.  I got the Title to work but it's not pulling the url.  Basically I just want to show the url that's not been cut of like what sometimes happens in the edit screen.  Here's my code:

```
function change_columns( $cols ) {
$cols = array(
'cb'       => '<input type="checkbox" />',
'title'       => __( 'Title'),
'url'      => __( 'URL',      'trans' ),
 );
return $cols;    
}
add_filter( "manage_cf-link_posts_columns", "change_columns" );

function custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;
switch ( $column ) {
case "url":
  $url = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true);
  echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url. '</a>';
  break;
}
}

add_action( "manage_cf-link_posts_custom_column", "custom_columns", 10, 2 );
```

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: are you sure that 'url' is the name of the field and that it has any content?

Comment: Why not `get_permalink( $post_id )`;?

Comment: I swore I tried that.. but it was 3:30 am.  I just replaced the get_post_meta with the get_permalink and it worked.  I think when I tried that I had forgotten to call the global $post variable.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, then I move my comment to an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use [`get_permalink( $post_id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) to get the URI of a post. It takes care of changed permalink structures and SSL.

Be aware that the similar named function [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) does **not** accept a parameter. To get the permalink of a custom post type (or a regular post outside of the [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)) you have to use `get_permalink()`.